# Is there a way to dynamically update/increment column values when a new value is added?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Apologies if the title doesn't communicate the question properly.

If I have a Postgres table called Person with the following columns and data:

```
name | age | order |
John | 42  | 1     |
Sam  | 27  | 2     |
Phil | 19  | 3     |
```

The order column is a Float that determines the order by which the client should display a list of persons.

Is there an optimal performant way to insert a Person with an existing order but delegating the DB to autoincrement the values in the order column? If so, how?

For example, if I insert a new person `(Emma, 56, 2)` I want the result to be

```
name | age | order |
John | 42  | 1     |
Sam  | 27  | 3     |
Phil | 19  | 4     |
Emma | 56  | 2     |
```

Note Sam and Phil now have their orders incremented.

**Possible solution:**
I can take advantage of float and get the average of the previous order value and current order. So in the above example, it would be 1 (for John) + 2 (for Emma in the insert) / 2. The new order for Emma will be 1.5 which fits nicely as shown below:

```
name | age | order |
John | 42  | 1     |
Sam  | 27  | 2     |
Phil | 19  | 3     |
Emma | 56  | 1.5   |
```

But this requires multiple DB calls hence the question.

Edit: While I went with George Joseph's answer in the final implementation, the correct answer that actually answered the question was clamp's. Hence I marked his answer as accepted.

Comment: What if you have million data in your table and you insert a new data.  Then you have to update almost whole table every time. If your table size is small, then you can create trigger on table.

Comment: @Abdusoli, yes, the table size is small. Or do you recommend the second solution?

Comment: In case your table size is small then creating trigger is a good solution. Because you do not want multiple DB calls.

Comment: One more question, assume you have ```John | 42 | 1 ``` . In this case John is in first order. What if you insert new name with age ```42```, then which one given high order?

Comment: Age doesn't matter in terms of the order. Just the values in the order column. The new record will always take precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the existing entries here is how:

First check if the new value conflicts with an existing one. If so, increment existing values by 1 (this would still worl with integers).

I use `sort_order` instead of `order` because the latter is reserved in SQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION person_check_sort_order() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$def$
BEGIN
PERFORM * FROM person WHERE sort_order = new.sort_order;
IF FOUND THEN
UPDATE person SET sort_order = sort_order + 1 WHERE sort_order >= new.sort_order;
END IF;
RETURN new;
END;
$def$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER person_insert_trg BEFORE INSERT ON person
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE person_check_sort_order();
```

Or you can do it recursively. This will work with updates too and stops when it reaches a gap in the order numbers  (assuming integer values):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_check_sort_order() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$def$
BEGIN
PERFORM * FROM person WHERE sort_order = new.sort_order;
IF FOUND THEN
UPDATE person SET sort_order = sort_order + 1 WHERE sort_order = new.sort_order;
END IF;
RETURN new;
END;
$def$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
--DROP TRIGGER person_insert_trg ON person;
CREATE TRIGGER person_insert_trg BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF sort_order ON person
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE person_check_sort_order();
```

Comment: Nice. This actually answers the initial question. I will let you know how the implementation goes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can work on the possible solution you have used in the example

You would pass the parameters, param_name,param_age and param_order

```
 insert 
   into t 
with data
  as (select (max(order) +max(:param_order))/2 as possible_solution 
        from t
        where order<:param_order 
      )
select :param_name,:param_age,d.possible_solution 
  from data d
```

Comment: Thanks, George. Why do you need the max(:param_order) on line 4 in this case? Why can't you just pass the param_order like so: (max(order) + param_order) /2?

Comment: You are right, that should work in postgresql i have tired that. In some other db it might have lead to familiar "not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 0):

I think sequence in PostgreSQL could solve this case

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial START 101;
```

you could find more details about this here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: No, a sequence will not work. A sequence can only give relative order of insertion as it constantly increases (at least in normal use). But OP requirement is to change the order so rows are not returned in insert order.  With the example data give the insert sequence for the desired required is 1,4,2,3. good thought, just not 1 that works in this case.